# Finding Specific data within custom-defined limits

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

Hi Folks,

Question 1)

I am trying to write a formula for the shown image, that does something like this:
(in order)

1) It selects rows in between "Recruiting" and "Total Recruiting"
2) Selects only AP accounts (leaves aside Insurance Accounts)
3) adds the debits and credits for the selected, filtered rows and gives me total.

So in nutshell for the final result, I am looking for **totals for debits (and credits both) for AP  transactions, for recruiting type of expenses** (in general there are more than 400 type of expenses, but I am trying to filter for specific type of expenses for this analysis). Is there a combined formula you can help me out with?

I could have copied "recruiting" over each row in the first column, filtered it, and got totals, but I want to avoid that since the total expense types are more than 400 and that is just a waste of time.

Question 2)

Is there a way I can find out one specific word (like we use CTRL + F) and add debits/credits for rows only corresponding to that word. for example if A1, D5, and F8 contain a specific word, Can i find this specific word, and find (and add) the debits and credits in the rows 1, 5, and 8? Please let me know if this sounds confusing.

Thank you, 
Ash

Comment: For Question 2, are you looking for the same word across all columns, or a specific word in each column?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for your first questions.

1) you can select the rows between "Recruiting and "Total Recruiting". You can use an `=ADDRESS(` Formula where,

`=ADDRESS(MATCH("Recruiting",$A:$A,0)+1,MATCH("Debits",$A$2:$E$2,0))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total Recruiting",$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH("Debits",$A$2:$E$2,0)) == $D$3:$D$6`

This will give you the range between "Recruiting and "Total Recruiting" in the debit column.

This will also be dynamic because if you insert rows the range should update on the fly.

To answer part 2 and 3 of your questions we can use this same methodology in a `=SUMIF(` formula.

Where,

```
=SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)

'Range =  (Accounts Payable Column)

INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Recruiting",$A:$A,0)+1,MATCH("AccountType",$A$2:$E$2,0))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total Recruiting",$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH("Account Type",$A$2:$E$2,0))),

'Criteria

"Accounts Payable",

'Sum_Range = (Debits Column)

INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Recruiting",$A:$A,0)+1,MATCH("Debits",$A$2:$E$2,0))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total Recruiting",$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH("Debits",$A$2:$E$2,0))))
```

Note I have added an extra header above for "Account Type" so the `=MATCH(` formula can find the right column. Alternatively you can replace the `MATCH` component in the `ADDRESS` formula and just insert a column number e.g. 2

[image]

After that, all you need to do is repeat the process for the "Credits" column.

You can do this simply but adjusting the `MATCH` for the sum_range to "Credits" instead of "Debits"